# Applying --add-opens Option to Dynamically Loaded Modules in Java 17

Tags: java, jvm, java-17, java-platform-module-system

In the context of JEP 403's robust encapsulation in Java 17, I have a class (.jar) that is dynamically loaded during JVM execution.
This class utilizes Reflection to invoke private methods belonging to the ClassLoader.

The JVM addresses this with the CLI option `--add-opens`, which allows specifying modules so that Reflection works successfully.
However, it seems that this approach is not applicable to modules that are loaded dynamically, meaning modules loaded after startup.

Currently, I am using like `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=foobar` and below code.

```
try
{
    Method method = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("findLoadedClass", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    // ...
}
catch (NoSuchMethodException | InaccessibleObjectException e)
{
    // InaccessibleObjectException will be thrown.
}
```

Then I got this warning on startup: `WARNING: Unknown module: foobar specified to --add-opens`

In an attempt to work around this limitation, I removed the `module-info.class` from my .jar, intending to load it as an unnamed module and use `--add-opens` for `ALL_UNNAMED` modules at JVM startup.
However, this approach is not viable due to other technical constraints.

Could someone please guide me on how to use --add-opens effectively for modules that are loaded dynamically after JVM startup?
Is there an alternative approach I should consider?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: How are you loading the module dynamically? Presumably you could use `Module::addOpens` after loading the module: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#addOpens(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)

Comment: I don't know much about class loading, but it is done by the framework's ClassLoader.
Using `addOpens` has failed with a documented IllegalCallerException.

Comment: You would also need to use the command line `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=<module>` for the module that calls `addOpens` for that to work. Essentially, the reflective `Module::addOpens` API allows a module to extend it's privilege to another module. If the loading is done through a framework, that framework might have an option to call `addOpens` for the modules that it loads. Then you would just have to give the framework module access through `--add-opens` on the command line.

Comment: What framework are you using? It would help if you included a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Currently, I'm using the Minecraft Forge framework. Thanks to your comment, I've started to come up with some specific solutions.

Since the framework's classes are loaded at JVM startup, you can open them with java.lang. By using ASM to perform Reflection operations with the framework's classes as the calling source, I believe the issue can be resolved.
In any case, I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: The equivalent to the `--add-opens` option can be applied right after the dynamic module layer has been created. That’s the crucial place: where the `foobar` module has been created an associated with your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you are faced with this error:
module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @75226b29

so to solve this, you must get "java.base" to open "java.security" to module unnamed module @75226b29 and as every time this module's name changes, you must open it for all unnamed modules with the below command:

--add-opens java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED